# Exclude (blacklist) multiple Json entries from loop from in PHP

Tags: php, json, loops, continue

I want to make a blacklist of entries I do not want to display on my page. The Json all the IDs so I can check which ones I like to exclude. If its one entry (i.e. `$eExceptions = '85';`) it works fine and the loop continues with the next entry. If there are multiple entries that I stored in an array it doesn't work. I assume because my 'if' statement can only handle one entry at a time.

How do I exclude all the entries in my array from the foreach loop? I think I have to make a foreach loop for each of the entries but then what?

```
<?php   
        foreach ($result -> data as $data){ 
            $eID            =   $data -> ID;
            $eExceptions    =   array("85", "95");

                if (!($eID == $eExceptions)) {

            ?> 

------show html etc------

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I'd suggest using http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use `in_array()` to check value exist or not in array

```
 if (!(in_array($eID,$eExceptions))) {
```

Comment: ah nice! I found that one but used it incorrectly. I used it as if (!($eID == in_array($eExceptions))) {. Thanks!